# How to call a certain object/menubar in a PHP file

Tags: php, templates, admin-menu, menus

I made a template and had some help with adding a CSS file to the template.

Now I'm stuck on the question, how do I add a certain menubar to my header.

Example: topbar - has menu with "Welcome %username%"

One more: I want to add the Wordpress Admin Bar to this template as well. How do I do that?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know how to include my header, but the header is far more than the menubar I need. And calling the menu bar via the header-include fills the whole header by stretching said bar.

Answer (score 0):

Since noone responded, here's my solution:

I copied my menubar from header.php into a new file called menubar.php and called that file with include("menubar.php");